# Rails Database Entry, Values are all question marks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, json

I am trying to run a create method in rails, to insert items into a database. The code for my create is as follows:

```
def create
  @song = Song.create ( { :song => params[:song],
  :artist => params[:artist],
  :album => params[:album],
  :song_id => params[:song_id],
  :longitude => params[:longitude],
  :latitude => params[:latitude],
  :stream_url => params[:stream_url],
  :art_url => params[:art_url] } )

  respond_to do |format|
    if @song.save
      format.json { render :json => @song, :status => :created, :location => @song }
    else
      format.json { render :json => @song.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

However, I get the following error message. How do I ensure that what I insert is what I want?

```
Started POST "/create" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun May 19 03:09:21 -0400 2013
Processing by SongsController#create as */*
Parameters: {"longitude"=>-72.6600766181946, "latitude"=>41.5570384662233, "album"=>"Get Lucky", "song"=>"Get Lucky", "artist"=>"Daft Punk", "stream_url"=>"http://api.7digital.com/1.2/track/preview?country=US&trackId=28905854&oauth_consumer_key=7dkn3ygtanwv", "art_url"=>"http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/026/861/0002686113_100.jpg", "song_id"=>28905854}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "songs" ("address", "album", "art_url", "artist", "created_at", "latitude", "longitude", "song", "song_id", "stream_url", "updated_at", "user") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["address", "2-16 McConaughy Drive, Wesleyan University, Middletown, CT 06457, USA"], ["album", "Get Lucky"], ["art_url", "http://cdn.7static.com/static/img/sleeveart/00/026/861/0002686113_100.jpg"], ["artist", "Daft Punk"], ["created_at", Sun, 19 May 2013 07:09:21 UTC +00:00], ["latitude", 41.5570384662233], ["longitude", -72.6600766181946], ["song", "Get Lucky"], ["song_id", 28905854], ["stream_url", "http://api.7digital.com/1.2/track/preview?country=US&trackId=28905854&oauth_consumer_key=7dkn3ygtanwv"], ["updated_at", Sun, 19 May 2013 07:09:21 UTC +00:00], ["user", nil]]
(47.1ms)  commit transaction
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  commit transaction
Completed 201 Created in 664ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 48.8ms)
```

Comment: Please show the corresponding view where you made the form.

Comment: -1 for pasting in code that scrolls that far to the right.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta Edit the post if you think line breaks will improve it. I think the long scroll is easier to read in this case. Voting down doesn't help (unless your comment was designed to attract votes for yourself).

Comment: I can edit a handful of posts where the formatting makes them difficult to read, but I don't have time to do it for every single one.  Down-voting helps by giving the OP feedback about formatting posts so it's easier to read and easier for people to help him.  You're accusing me of designing my comment to attract votes?  I'm struggling to imagine your thought process.  Is that even something people do?  What part of my comment is even remotely "attractive" to votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-> `Completed 201 Created`

There is no error message. The record was saved.

```
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ...values ->...
```

Those question marks are **placeholders** for the values that immediately follow. This is normal behavior.

Each question mark is replaced by following values in the order they are read. Scroll to the right to see those values. Looks like everything is there.

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

This is a security issue. Have you included `<%= csrf_meta_tags %>` in your layout?